# Showing data in blocks

Tags: html, css

I am displaying items from my database. The items are displayed in this pattern

```
ITEM 1 
Image
Desc
Link

ITEM 2 
Image
Desc
Link
```

I want ITEM2  to align on the right side of the ITEM 1.

How to do this?

Comment: Sounds like a CSS/HTML issue rather than anything to do with MySQL or PHP.

Comment: Yes i want the 2nd loop for ITEM 2 should show on right side of ITEM1 instead down to ITEM1

Comment: your question has to be readable for others to understand and answer. Tagging un necessary tags, will not do any good. Make your question simple and clearly understandable.

Use @user514529, solution !!

Answer (score 2):

Either [float using CSS](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/clearing.html) or if you have many divs, have a look at [jQuery Masonry](http://masonry.desandro.com/)

Answer (score 2):

Just use `float:left`

HTML:

```
<div id="item1">div1</div>
<div id="item2">div2</div>
```

CSS:

```
#item1{ float:left; }    
#item2{ float:left; }
```

Answer (score 0):

set width on each item and 
float it left